# How to configure webapp2 routes to run with HTTPS scheme in production but not in development?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2, google-app-engine-python

I have an webapp2 WSGI app which runs on App-Engine. How do I configure its routes with HTTPS scheme when the app is running in production but if it's running in development environment it should use HTTP scheme ?

EDIT: As suggested, I am adding a link which points webapp2 routing schemes

http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#restricting-uri-schemes

Comment: Do you want https to be mandatory in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply enable https in your app's app.yaml like below:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

You will then get https on appengine but devapp_server will still serve everything on http

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do something like this:

```
scheme = 'http' if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Development') else 'https'

webapp2.Route(..., schemes=[scheme])
```

Comment: This is not the case of app making a request to itself. If I set scheme as https, then the app returns 404 in development environment. I have to manually remove the scheme for the URL and then remember to put it back before deploying it to production.

Comment: Are you referring to these schemes? http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#restricting-uri-schemes